# Sencha Architect iOS app location

Tags: ios, iphone, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, ipa

I am working in Sencha Architect and when I click "Build iOS app" there are no errors and I get the message Package succesfull.

However I cannot find where the ".ipa" file is located.

Am I supposed to upload it manually to Phonegap?

Here is the output:

http://pastebin.com/z45vLARX

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will produce a .app file and not an ipa.  However I recommend not using the built-in packager as it's soon to be deprecated.  I'd use phonegap with Sencha Cmd

http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/11/20/SenchaPhoneGap/
http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/cordova

if you are using Architect:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?282369-Sencha-Architect-3x-with-Cordova-PhoneGap